# Is it necessary to fork again for future PRs?

Tags: github, pull-request

I created a pull request from my fork of the repository. I had made 10 commits to my fork for the pull request which was later merged.

Now when I want to work on another issue my fork still shows that it is 10 commits ahead of the main repository even though the PR was merged. I deleted my fork of the repository and forked the repository again. Now it shows my fork is up to date with the main repository (as expected).

So my question is do I need to delete my fork and create new fork of main repository for every new pull request?

Comment: It is recommended not to make the changes in the main branch (master or main) of your fork but to create a new branch and from there do the PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. Like [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) said just make a new branch on the fork and make the PR pulling the changes from that new branch.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the branch of fork can be deleted after the PR is merged and newer branches have to be created for newer issues (which is more convenient) ?
Also the main branch of fork remains untouched with changes in other branches?

Comment: @ATB You are correct that the main branch is not affected. It is only affected when the PR is merged and you make sure the main branch is up to date.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Ethan, this really helps me as someone getting started with GitHub.